# iOS: Lazy-loading in UIScrollView with ARC

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, automatic-ref-counting, lazy-loading

I'm working on an iPad-App with ARC which have to display thousands of UIImageViews in a UIScrollView...

When I load them all at once (or more accurately in a queue with GCD), I run out of memory after a while of loading..

Now, I thought i have to use lazy-loading and load only those UIImages which are     necessary and a kind of release those which are no longer visible, but I don't know if this is possible with ARC..

Anybody have an idea to do this, or a better idea to handle this case..?

Thanks, tonistair

Comment: This happens automatically with tableViewCells if you can put them in a tableview....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make something that implements UIScrollViewDelegate, and in its viewDidScroll method, calculate the currently visible rect from contentOffset and bounds. Then remove things that are no longer visible, and add things that have just become visible (or some other appropriate algorithm). ARC has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I agree. Instead of releasing, you'd just have to remove the image from the superView (assuming nothing else is retaining it) and then set it to nil, ARC will take care of deallocating it.

Comment: Thank you, i don't know why i overlooked this option ^^